# TCP communication with Socket in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, sockets, server, tcp, listener

I need to create a Server for a TCP Communication in Vb.
I have found this code online:

```
        server = New TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 2000)
        server.Start()
        TextBox2.Text = "Server avviato... In attesa che quelcuno si connetta!"
        Timer1.Start()
```

Anyway when i run this code it throws me this exception.

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: The port 2000 is already being used. I would recommend using a port between 10000 and 32000 for your listener. Also, you should set the reuse address property of the socket so that the socket will get closed immediately when your program finishes executing and you won’t have some phantom program holding on to the socket.

Comment: The following may be of interest: [TCP overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/sockets/tcp-classes)

Comment: @SupaMaggie70b "*... so that the socket will get closed immediately when your program finishes executing ...*" - that is not what `ReuseAddress` does. The socket port will still be closed normally. Enabling `ReuseAddress` simply allows a listener to open a previously-closed port that the OS hasn't released yet. Perhaps what you are thinking of is disabling `Linger` instead?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Good call. I misspoke. Regardless, it is to a similar effect but I appreciate you pointing that out.